# Count the number of subdirectories or files in Python

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

So I need to count the number of subdirectories OR the number of files (depending on what user wants to do) in directory (recursive and non recursive). I did it in C#, but I'm very new in Python. I found this:

```
(len([f for f in os.listdir(directory)]))
```

but this code counts everything in directory (files, subdirectories), while I need only subdirectories or only files, but not them together. Is there a function to solve that question?
Thanks for all replies in advance!

Comment: I'm sure you will find something in https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cue [os.walk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)!

How about something like this:

```
import os

n_dirs = 0
n_files = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=False):
   n_files += len(files)
   n_dirs += len(dirs)
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it should get the job done. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using glob method of pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(your_path)
num_of_sub_dirs, num_of_files = 0, 0
# if you want to check inside sub-directories as well, then use path.rglob('*')
for f in path.glob('*'): 
    print(f.name)
    if f.is_dir():
        num_of_sub_dirs += 1
    if f.is_file():
        num_of_files += 1

print(num_of_sub_dirs, num_of_files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/glob.html#glob.glob) can be a solution:

```py
import os
import glob

# Remove one for the root directory
print(len(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "**"), recursive=True)) - 1)
```